# DialogFragment : How to prevent animating again and again? e.g. after backstage

Tags: android, animation, dialogfragment

Here is a custom DialogFragment. It works well in the single activity, but when the app is in backstage and comes back, it starts its pop-in animation again. So how to prevent this case?

```java
public class GdtFeedbackFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private static final String TAG = GdtFeedbackFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.GdtTransparentFeedbackFragmentStyle);
        if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.getDecorView().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();

            window.getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimationLandscape;
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AdLog.i(TAG, "[onCreateView]");
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.gdt_feedback_fragment_portrait,
                container);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem probably doesn't lie in the dialog class itself but where it is used. You need to look at the code for displaying the dialog and try to find out under what circumstances this can be called when re-showing a fragment

Answer (score 0):

when you closing popup you can call "dialog.dismiss". And you can this following code.

*MyDialogFragment:*

```html
package com.gotrend.views;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import com.gotrend.R;
import com.gotrend.base.MyApplication;
import com.gotrend.databinding.DialogFragmentPinBinding;
import com.gotrend.utils.GeneralUtils;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.Objects;

public class DialogFragmentPIN extends DialogFragment {
    @Inject
    GeneralUtils utils;

    private DialogFragmentPinBinding binding;
    private DialogFragmentPINListener listener;

    public interface DialogFragmentPINListener {
        void onConfirmButtonClicked(String pincode);
    }

    public void setListener(DialogFragmentPINListener listener){this.listener = listener;}

    public DialogFragmentPIN() {
        // Empty constructor is required for DialogFragment
        // Make sure not to add arguments to the constructor
    }

    public static DialogFragmentPIN newInstance() {
        DialogFragmentPIN frag = new DialogFragmentPIN();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MyApplication.getApp().getNetComponent().inject(this);
        binding = DialogFragmentPinBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        listeners();

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Window window = Objects.requireNonNull(getDialog()).getWindow();
        Objects.requireNonNull(window).setLayout((int) (utils.getScreenWidth() * 0.95), WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void listeners() {

        binding.confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              
                listener.onConfirmButtonClicked(pin);
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyActivity

```html
DialogFragmentPIN dialogFragment = DialogFragmentPIN.newInstance(bundle);
        dialogFragment.setListener((size, pos) -> {
           
        });
        dialogFragment.show(fm, "FragmentMyDialog");
```